# ResultSet.next() returns false

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

In DB2 I execute a select statement and get the ResultSet as below

```
PreparedStatement ps;
ps = connection.prepareStatement("myQuery");
ps.setString(1, "data");
ps.execute();
ResultSet rs;
rs = ps.getResultSet();
```

For some reason, I get `rs.next()` as `false` sometimes which means it returns 0 rows, whereas if I execute the same query on the database I get 2 rows. I
I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
PreparedStatement ps;
ps = connection.prepareStatement("myQuery");
ps.setString(1, "data");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
;
```

Comment: @EJP but the first part of my answer was for OP's initial question, i did mention **EDIT** for my second part though, can you retrieve your downvote now ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I was using two databases and the other database was able to match the case of the value `data` set as parameter for the query, it was `DATA` in the database and db2 wasn't quite like that, my mistake that I wasn't able to figure it out.